# Solve $\frac{dx}{x+z}=\frac{dy}{y}=\frac{dz}{y^2+z}$

Tags: partial-differential-equations, linear-pde

$$\frac{dx}{x+z}=\frac{dy}{y}=\frac{dz}{y^2+z}$$
Just a standard largarange auxillairy equation of the pde of quassi linear form, i tried grouping ,basic properties of ratios,but nothing seems to work.

Comment: The following formulation of your characteristic equations may be useful: $$x’(t)=x(t),\quad y’(t)=y(t),\quad z’(t)=y(t)^2+z(t)$$ where $t$ is the ‘time’ along the characteristic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take the last two equations:
$$
\frac{dy}{y} = \frac{dz}{y^2+z}
$$
Rearrange the cross-ratio:
$$
dy - \frac{ydz - zdy}{y^2} = 0 
$$
The second term is the differential of the ratio, after which integration becomes straightforward:
$$
dy - d\left(\frac{z}{y}\right) = 0 
$$
$$
z = y(y-C_1)
$$
Now take the first two equation:
$$
\frac{dx}{x+z} = \frac{dy}{y}
$$
$$
zdy = ydx - xdy
$$
$$
\frac{z}{y}\frac{dy}{y} = \frac{ydx - xdy}{y^2}
$$
Now using the first integral:
$$
\frac{(y-C_1)dy}{y} = d\left(\frac{x}{y}\right)
$$
Finally:
$$
y-C_1\ln{|y|} = \frac{x}{y}+C_2
$$

Answer (score 1):

$$\frac{dx}{x+z}=\frac{dy}{y}=\frac{dz}{y^2+z}$$
I suppose that the above Charpit-Lagrange system of ODEs comes from solving the PDE :
$$(x+z)\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}+y\frac{\partial z}{\partial y}=y^2+z \tag 1$$
A first characteristic equation comes from $\frac{dy}{y}=\frac{dz}{y^2+z}$

$\frac{dz}{dy}=y-\frac{z}{y}\quad$ is a first order linear ODE easy to solve : $z=y^2+c_1y$
$$\frac{z}{y}-y=c_1$$

A second characteristic equation comes from $\frac{dx}{x+z}=\frac{dy}{y}=\frac{dx}{x+(y^2+c_1y)}$

$\frac{dx}{dy}=\frac{x}{y}+y+c_1$ is a first order linear ODE easy to solve for $x(y)$ :

$\frac{x}{y}-y-c_1\ln|y|=c_2$
$$\frac{x}{y}-y-(\frac{z}{y}-y)\ln|y|=c_2$$
The general solution of the PDE $(1)$ on the form of implicit equation $\Phi(c_1,c_2)=0$ is :
$$\Phi\left((\frac{z}{y}-y) \:,\:(\frac{x}{y}-y-(\frac{z}{y}-y)\ln|y|)\right)=0$$
$\Phi$ is an arbitrary function of two variables.

$\Phi$ has to be determined according to some boundary condition.